# PostgreSQL: pg_restore with append?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Is there some way to tell `pg_restore` to only append rows that don't already exist?

---

Background: I'm trying to restore an **archive-db** from a **main-db**. Both are using PostgreSQL 12.

The catch is I don't want to keep lots of the table entries on my **main-db**. I generally only care about entries in the last few hours, but need everything to be pretty fast so I want to drop old data on the **main-db**.

There is a small use case to keep old data around though, so for that I'd like to run `pg_dump` on the **main-db** to dump my data to a file before I drop old data. Then on the **archive-db** I want to use `pg_restore` to add the new stuff without loosing any old rows that existed on the **main-db** in previous iterations of this workflow.

I don't see an [append option in the `pg_restore` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) but it seems like something that should exist, so other suggestions for how to approach this problem are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: There is no append procedure for ```pg_restore```. You will have to do something else, probably a custom built solution.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: Another option is to create your archive as a table with the same structure and column names in the same database then create procedure to insert into the archive and delete from main. Finally create a VIEW that merges the main and archive for those times where the history is needed. If you run the archive regularly (daily or shorter intervals) performance should be satisfactory and you do not have the worry of the lack of append option on pg_restore, not recovery operations for data not yet archived.

Comment: Thanks for your advise @AdrianKlaver – I'm trying monthly partitions to start. Seems like this will help preserve performance while keeping all my data together and not requiring custom functions to move it around.